# Plotting the histogram of a very huge pyspark column

Tags: pyspark

Related question: [Pyspark: show histogram of a data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154325/pyspark-show-histogram-of-a-data-frame-column)

I have a very long column that I cannot convert it to pandas as suggested in the above topic (spark ran out of memory).

How can I plot the histogram of this column?

Comment: In the related question, the last option transforms to pandas only the resulting histogram. Doesn't that option work in your case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154325/pyspark-show-histogram-of-a-data-frame-column

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get a representative histogram from a randomly sampled subset of the data. Maybe start with 1% as below:

```
dfs = df.sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=0.01, seed=None).toPandas()
```

then see if memory allows `dfs.hist()`

Down-sampling large columns & data frames is perfectly legitimate in many applications of data science (although it can be troublesome when hunting for rare events). Repeat the procedure a number of times (with `seed=None`) and compare the results to set your mind at ease.