# how can i plot a histogram in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am new on pyspark , I have tabe as below, I want to plot histogram of this df , x axis will include  “word” by axis will include “count” columns. Do you have any idea ?

```
  word         count
  Akdeniz’in    14
  en            13287
  büyük         3168
  deniz         1276
  festivali:    6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark: show histogram of a data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154325/pyspark-show-histogram-of-a-data-frame-column)

Comment: @pault i tried it but i got error which is related with "word" column is not integer therfore i couldn't plot , any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a histogram is not the correct diagram typ to visualize a word count. Histograms are useful to visualize the distribution of a variable,  bar charts in contrary are used to compare variables (Read this [article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/naomirobbins/2012/01/04/a-histogram-is-not-a-bar-chart/#504362e6d775) for more information). With the following code you can create a barchart for your example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot 
l = [(  'Akdeniz’in',    14)
     ,('en'         ,   13287)
     ,('büyük'       ,  3168)
     ,('deniz'        , 1276)
     ,('festivali:'   , 6)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['word','count'])
#Add values to a list (not recommend when you have a huge dataframe)
bla = df.collect()
#create a numeric value for every label
indexes = list(range(len(bla)))

#split words and counts to different lists 
values = [r['count'] for r in bla]
labels = [r['word'] for r in bla]

#Plotting
bar_width = 0.35

pyplot.bar(indexes, values)

#add labels
labelidx = [i + bar_width for i in indexes] 
pyplot.xticks(labelidx, labels)
pyplot.show()
```

[image: Sample plot]